# Is it safe to mv files to and from two drives simultaneously?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, synology, mv

I have two disks on my Synology DS215j. Disk 1 is `/volume1` and disk 2 is `/volume2`.

```
                          size of folder
disk   capacity    free    to move from
----   --------   ------  --------------
  1      2TB        1 TB      0.6 TB
  2      2TB      0.5 TB      1.5 TB
```

I'd like to move a big folder (1.5 TB) from disk 2 to disk 1, but there is not enough space on disk 1.

Is it safe to start another `mv` 0.6 TB from disk 1 to disk 2 at the same time of `mv` 1TB from disk 2 to disk 1?

Comment: Rather than moving them simultaneously, why not start by moving parts of the data at a time? For example, move .8TB from disk 2 to disk 1, move the .6TB from disk 1 to disk 2, and then move the rest of the folder to disk 1.  If you have large files, you can `split` the files into smaller pieces, move them, and `cat` them back together later. For more info, take a look here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1588/break-a-large-file-into-smaller-pieces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can*, but be prepared for the inevitable race conditions that occur. It's hard to be certain the transfers will run at a 1:1 ratio, and one may take priority.

You may need to monitor it and be ready to change nice values to give one of them priority over the other if it balances incorrectly.

Note also that it will take a long while as it'll be seeking all over the place.